# fulltext mysql search and match exact string

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Ok this is doing my grey matter in I've read and been through mysql and looked at various options and I can only think its so obvious I'm just blind.

In short i'm making a tag cloud and part of the process is to verify if the word exists and if so +1 but it has to be the exact phrase.

So I took the view that fulltext search would be the best option.

So as an example.

```
$string = "hair dryer";

$string = '"'.$string.'"'; //enclose string in quotation marks to define must be an exact match



 //$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$string); // removed to see if this was effecting the result.

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `search_keyword` WHERE Match (`keyword`) Against ('$string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1";
 $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
```

So the test was in the DB I have a line with the word "hair dryer" and it matches it - good result

However if I change the string to "hair" it still pulls out "hair dryer" which it shouldn't do as its not an exact match.

I've read all over and every way I try this I get the wrong result.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [keyword] => hair dryer
        [id] => 25
    )

 )  /// should be empty and hair as a single row is not found
```

Please any advice is welcomed :-)

Comment: Then why not `SELECT count(*) FROM ... WHERE Keyword = $string`. If you only want a certain match.

Comment: Yes it does work using that method, however every so often for some reason it fails to pick up an existing word and adds another to the table when it shouldn't. So I thought that if I used fulltext I would get a more accurate method and not create duplicates. I'm confused as to why its seems so hard to get the query to pull out only an exact match.

Comment: if i understand your problem correctly the Full text search is not the correct direction, because Full text create inverted index even you will set the limit char limit to 1 then also 'hair' will going to match 'hair dryer'. 
You need to work with PHP like process your keyword before query like trim,strtolower then use following query SELECT count(*) FROM ... WHERE Keyword = trim($string) or Group query on Keyword field.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with php. First transform your string into an array and then compare both arrays to see if there is a match.

```
      $string = explode(" ",$string); 
      $sql = "SELECT keyword FROM search_keyword";
     $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$compareArrays = array_intersect($result,$string);
       if (is_array($compareArrays) && count($compareArrays) > 0) {
```

Do something with the result as if $compareArrays is greter than one, it means you have an exact match. array_intersect compares 2 arrrays to see if there is an exact match. This way I don't think you would get a match with 'hair' as a string but you would get one with 'hair dryer'. Does this work?